# Sharing and editing numpy array in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I was experimenting on numpy with multiprocessing in python I've read numerous tutorials and stackoverflow answers.
I wrote a code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
import numpy as np

def main():
    im_arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,6,7]])
    print('Array in main before process:',im_arr)

    shape = im_arr.shape
    size = im_arr.size
    im_arr.shape = size
    arr = Array('B', im_arr)   
    p = Process(target=fun, args=(arr,shape))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    arr = np.frombuffer(arr.get_obj(), dtype=np.uint8)
    arr.shape = shape
    print('Array in main after process:',arr)

def fun(a, shape):
    a = np.frombuffer(a.get_obj(), dtype=np.uint8)
    a.shape = shape

    a[0][0] = 10
    a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
    a[0][0] = 5

    print('Array inside function:',a)
    a.shape = shape[0]*shape[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What i hoped to do was to share a numpy array and to edit the array in another process while the change can also be observed in main program.
But the output i get is as follows

```
('Array in main before process:', array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 6, 7]]))
('Array inside function:', array([[5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]))
('Array in main after process:', array([[10,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  6,  7]], dtype=uint8))
```

it seems like 'a' in the function behaves like a new independent object after the numpy array is saved to it.

Please correct what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems like 'a' in the function behaves like a new independent object after the numpy array is saved to it.

Well, this is partly true. With `np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])` you create a new independent object and then with `a =`  attach the label `a` to it. From  then on the label `a` doesn't point to the shared array anymore.

If you want to save a new array in the shared memory you can use

```
a[...] = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
```

(This is actually valid syntax, `...` is called the ellipsis literal)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using memory mapping for this.  First, create your array in one of the processes:

```
im_arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,6,7]])
```

Then, save it to disk:

```
np.save('im_arr.npy', im_arr)
```

Then, load it in each process, with `mode='r+'` so you can modify it:

```
im_arr = np.load('im_arr.npy', 'r+')
```

Now the contents will be visible to both processes at all times.

Comment: is `np.save()` faster than `cpickle`ing..?

Comment: @AnuragJk: In general, yes.  Try it and see.